# iOS - Initializing uitableViewCells?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I was watching the 2011 WWDC tutorial for storyboards.
In the tutorial I noticed the following code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSindexPath *__strong)indexPath
{
    // The identifier is defined in the storyboard
    MyCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCustomCell"];
    return cell;
}
```

**QUESTION:**
Is this a new feature in iOS 5 that doesn't require you to initialize a cell before trying to reuse it?
I feel like there is too much magic in iOS 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right. Instead of having to make a nib for a custom cell, you can edit a prototype cell in Storyboard. All you have to do is set the Identifier in Storyboard, and then you can get cells from `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` without having to allocate and initialize them yourself.

Answer (score -1):

No. The UITableView Class Reference documentation of dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: still indicates that this method returns a cell only if there is one in the queue. If there isn't, then you need to initialize one. I'm not sure why a 2011 WWDC tutorial would imply to the contrary.